# Can I Determine When a Domain Class is Added?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

If I have 2 (or more) domain classes with a hasMany of `C`, how can I determine if an entity of `C` has been added?

```
class A {
    String name
    static hasMany = [cs: C]
class B {
    String name
    static hasMany = [cs: C]
}
class C {
    String someProperty
}

// In CController add Action
//...
genericInstance.addToCs(cInstance)
```

I'm looking for more of an event I can handle. `CController` is used for inline forms for `A` and `B`, but I need two different processes to run depending on which domain `C` is added to

Comment: if (cInstance in genericInstance.cs) ?

Comment: Have you tried to write your own `addToCs` method / Closure in class `C`?

Comment: @Isammoc I'll consider that your answer, if you re-write it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the possibility to write your own `addToCs` method / Closure in your classes `A` and `B`.

```
class A {
    String name
    static hasMany = [cs: C]
    def addToCs = {
        // Do what you want with your value
        cs.add(C)
    }
}
```

Be aware of what happens in default `addToCs` :
[DomainClassGrailsPlugin.groovy:289 @github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/651454b5a1ed0d8bf8be5e0c59980f7ae296b106/grails-plugin-domain-class/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/DomainClassGrailsPlugin.groovy#L289)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just consolidate A and B into one domain, given that they have identical properties?

I'd recommend to do like this:

```
class AB {
    char type
    String name
    static hasMany = [cs: C]

    static constraints = {
        type inList:['A','B']     //you can extend to 'C', 'D'... easily with this
    }
}
class C {
    String someProperty
}
```

In Controller you can do:

```
abInstance.addToCs(cInstance)
def domainTag = abInstance.type
```

Then domainTag is what you want.

Comment: No, because `A` and `B` in reality are two completely different domains. My example is pseudo-code.